# What are convenient ways to refer to a MultiIndex level in a DataFrame object?

Tags: python, pandas

Given the filter using the MultiIndex levels

```
dataframe.loc[(dataframe.index.get_level_values('level_A') != value)
            & (dataframe.index.get_level_values('level_B') != value2)
            & ... ]
```

Are there any shorthand alternatives for `dataframe.index.get_level_values` within the `pandas` package?

I would prefer referring to the index levels in the similar way we look up the DataFrame columns, for instance:

```
dataframe.loc[(dataframe[('level_A')] != value)
            & (dataframe[('level_B')] != value2)
            & ... ]
```

Writing additional `lambdas df, level: df.get_level_values(level)` in every separate project could also be somewhat inconvenient.

Comment: Take a look at [Multiindex Slicer](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-mi-slicers)

Comment: kindly provide sample dataframe, with expected output